# Error Processing CityData

Tags: warning-messages, curated-data

I try get the populations of all cities by this common used line

```
pop0 = Map[{#, CityData[#, "Population"]} &, CityData[All]];
```

But it gives me this error message

```
Part::partw: Part 115371 of {944864,944864,944866,944871,945025,945039,945059,945073,945073,945107,945112,945073,945127,945136,945145,945151,945156,945156,945165,945190,945221,945226,945073,945073,945804,944864,944864,945809,945814,945968,945986,945059,945073,945073,946006,946011,945073,946030,946039,946048,946058,945156,945156,945165,946063,945221,946098,945073,945073,945804,<<115100>>} does not exist. >>
```

Can someone explain what exactly happens here and how I can fix this?

Comment: The code runs fine for me. `10.4`

Comment: Do you have the full version of *Mathematica*? Otherwise you might be running into memory issues.

Comment: I know that the code should run. I've  found it in multiple examples. I am using Mathematica 10.4 student version and have plenty of ram left.